# PowerShell : Script unable to open native file in archive, but able for newly created file

Tags: powershell, shell, zip, admin

**Hi guys !**

I've created a powershell script that goes through some archive files to do some simple text editing in one of the files.

My problem is rather simple, when I want to open and edit xxx.ini, it fails. 
Yet, when I add a test.ini *(or delete xxx.ini, and add it back)*, and try to run the exact same script on this new file, it works.

I tried looking for the **IsReadOnly** property, but it returns false.

Can anyone help with this ?

```
        if ($f -notmatch "bulkPrefEditor"){
            # The zip file to be updated
            $file = $f

            # Is the file read only ? Let's try to force that to false
            $isReadOnly = Get-ItemProperty -Path $file | Select-Object IsReadOnly
            Write-Log "Is $file Read-Only : $isReadOnly" "INFO" $logfile
            Set-ItemProperty -Path $file -Name IsReadOnly -Value $false


            Write-Log "Editing following file : $f" "INFO" $logfile

            # Load ZipFile (Compression.FileSystem) if necessary
            try { $null = [IO.Compression.ZipFile] }
            catch { [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.IO.Compression.FileSystem') }

            # Open zip file with update mode (Update, Read, Create -- are the options)
            try { 
                $fileZip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open( $file, 'Update' )
            }
            catch {
                Write-Log "Another process has locked the '$file' file." "ERROR" $logfile
                Write-Log "Another process has locked the '$file' file."
                continue
            }

            # Finding the specific file within the zip file
            try{
                $fileZip.Entries | Where-Object { $_.FullName -match "$innerpath" }
            } catch {
                Write-Log "Could not find $filepath\$innerpath in $f , have you used anti-slash instead of slash ?" "WARN" $logfile
                Write-Log "Could not find $filepath\$innerpath in $f , have you used anti-slash instead of slash "
                continue
            }
            pause
            # If needed, read the contents of specific file to $text and release the file so to use streamwriter later
            try{
                $desiredFile = [System.IO.StreamReader]($fileZip.Entries | Where-Object { $_.FullName -match "$innerpath" }).Open()
                $text = $desiredFile.ReadToEnd()
                $desiredFile.Close()
                $desiredFile.Dispose()
            }
            catch {
                Write-Log "Could not read $f/$innerpath in $f " "WARN" $logfile
                Write-Log "Could not read $f/$innerpath in $f "
                continue
            }
```

Result :
[image]

I've added some simple logs to my script :

> 2019/11/21 18:40:12 INFO #################### STARTING SCRIPT... ####################
>   2019/11/21 18:40:12 INFO This Script will operate on files contained in C:\Users\pfournet\Documents\Factory\BulkPrefEditor
>   2019/11/21 18:40:12 INFO This script can see (4) files.
>   2019/11/21 18:40:12 INFO List of available files (single line) : 20191119-123448387 - Copie (2).zip 20191119-123448387 - Copie.zip 20191119-123448387.zip BulkPrefEditor.ps1 BulkPrefEditor_Zip.ps1
>   2019/11/21 18:40:12 INFO This file has been found : 20191119-123448387 - Copie (2).zip
>   2019/11/21 18:40:12 INFO This file has been found : 20191119-123448387 - Copie.zip
>   2019/11/21 18:40:12 INFO This file has been found : 20191119-123448387.zip
>   2019/11/21 18:40:12 INFO This Script will replace this line : use-compression = true with use-compression = false
>   2019/11/21 18:40:12 INFO #################### COMMENCING OPERATIONS ####################
>   2019/11/21 18:40:12 INFO Is 20191119-123448387 - Copie (2).zip Read-Only : @{IsReadOnly=False}
>   2019/11/21 18:40:12 INFO Editing following file : 20191119-123448387 - Copie (2).zip
>   2019/11/21 18:40:13 WARN Could not read 20191119-123448387 - Copie (2).zip/ul-flow/plugins/interactivedata.ini in 20191119-123448387 - Copie (2).zip 
>   2019/11/21 18:40:13 INFO Is 20191119-123448387 - Copie.zip Read-Only : @{IsReadOnly=False}
>   2019/11/21 18:40:13 INFO Editing following file : 20191119-123448387 - Copie.zip
>   2019/11/21 18:40:13 WARN Could not read 20191119-123448387 - Copie.zip/ul-flow/plugins/interactivedata.ini in 20191119-123448387 - Copie.zip 
>   2019/11/21 18:40:13 INFO Is 20191119-123448387.zip Read-Only : @{IsReadOnly=False}
>   2019/11/21 18:40:13 INFO Editing following file : 20191119-123448387.zip
>   2019/11/21 18:40:14 WARN Could not read 20191119-123448387.zip/ul-flow/plugins/interactivedata.ini in 20191119-123448387.zip 
>   2019/11/21 18:40:14 INFO #################### ENDING SCRIPT... ####################

Comment: This probably isn't a filesystem permission problem. When you open a Zip file with `[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open( $file, 'Update' )` you have locked it for editing. Make sure you call `$fileZip.Dispose()` to finish writing it, otherwise your script will fail on it's second run. I spent a lot of time debugging that problem when I wrote [this script](https://github.com/mossrich/PowershellRecipes/blob/master/ArchiveOldLogs.ps1)

Answer (score 1):

As Rich Moss mentioned in their comment, your script as written is not disposing of the objects and you are keeping locks out on the zip file. My initial solution to this was to extract all the files from the archive, modify the file that you need, then rezip.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

$file = Get-ChildItem C:\temp\test3.zip

$tempOutputFolder = "c:\temp\$(New-Guid)"

[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($file.FullName, $tempOutputFolder)

$zippedFilesToEdit = Get-ChildItem $tempOutputFolder -Recurse -File | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "new 1" }

foreach ($zippedFile in $zippedFilesToEdit){
    #Modifiy your file, and save it
    Get-Content $zippedFile | for-each {$_ -replace "Pattern","ReplaceWith"} | Out-File $zippedFile.FullName
}

Remove-Item $file.FullName
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($tempOutputFolder,$file.FullName)
```

This is not as flexible as modifying the file object directly from the archive. If you have a big archive/files this will take too long, so I sat down to do it via a stream. This script works, but I am sure there could be improvements. (I think we could actually just edit the stream directly) Also, the error handling could be better. We want to make sure we close/dispose of all the objects on completion of failure, so we need a try/catch/finally block around the whole thing, which requires us to check for individual errors, repackage them and throw (`Write-Error -ErrorAction Stop) them again. This can make debugging harder, because you will not see the actual line number of the error. You have to make sure when you catch the errors that you are properly handling both expected and unexpected errors properly.

This runs for me on Win 10/PS 5.1.

**EDIT** I added code at the beginning and end which will test this out by creating a zip archive with 10 generated files, reporting the size, then performing the edit operation and unzipping to check the size of the modified files. 
**This code will remove files from the $Test* locations. Read the script before you run it so you know what it will do before you hit F5**

```
$TestPath = "C:\temp\zipTest"
$testZipPath = "C:\temp\ZipTest.zip"
$filePathToFind = "test 1.txt"

If (-not (Test-Path $TestPath)){New-Item -Path $TestPath -ItemType Directory}
foreach( $i in 1..10){
   "Some Text/file contents" | Set-Content -Path "$TestPath\test $i.txt" 
}
Remove-Item -Path $testZipPath -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($TestPath,$testZipPath)

Write-Host "File sizes before any operation: "
Get-ChildItem $testZipPath | foreach { Write-Host "filename: $($_.Name), length: $($_.Length)"}
Write-Host "test zip file size: $(Get-ChildItem $testZipPath | select -ExpandProperty Length)"

$file = $testZipPath
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Running the opertion to modify the file in the archive"
try{

    # Check if zip files exists, and can open the file, then open if possible
    If(-not (Test-Path $file)){Write-Error "Zip File does not exist" -ErrorAction Stop}
    try { $fileZip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open( $file, 'Update' ) }
    catch { Write-Error "Another process has locked the '$file' file." -ErrorAction Stop }

    # Finding the specific file within the zip file
    try{ $fileZip.Entries | Where-Object { $_.FullName -eq $filePathToFind } | Out-Null} 
    catch { Write-Error "Could not find $filePathToFind in $file." -ErrorAction Stop }

    # If needed, read the contents of specific file to $text and release the file so to use streamwriter later
        #Get the entry in the archive that you want to modify
        $zippedEntry = $fileZip.Entries | Where-Object { $_.FullName -eq $filePathToFind }
        if($zippedEntry -eq $null){Write-Error "Could not find entry in zip file" -ErrorAction Stop}
        #Open the file as a stream
        $desiredFile = [System.IO.StreamReader]($zippedEntry).Open() 
        #Read the entire contents to a string variable (Maybe you could manipulate the stream but not sure how to do that)
        $text = $desiredFile.ReadToEnd()

        #Cleanup
        $desiredFile.Close() | Out-Null
        $desiredFile.Dispose()| Out-Null

        #Modify the contents as needed. In this case I am just setting the contents to a bunch of numbers
        [string]$newText = ((1..1000) | % {"$_`n"})

        #Delete the entry in the archive
        $zippedEntry.Delete()
        #Create a new (empty) entry at the path inside the archive
        $newEntry = $fileZip.CreateEntry($filePathToFind)

        #Open the new entry as a stream and write the new text to it
        $stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] $newEntry.Open()
        $stream.Write($newText)
        $stream.Close()
}
catch {
    throw
}
finally{
    # You want to dispose of everything in a finally block so that the objects get removed even if an error is thrown 
    $desiredFile.Close() | Out-Null
    $desiredFile.Dispose()| Out-Null
    $stream.Close() | Out-Null
    $fileZip.Dispose()| Out-Null
}
Write-Host "Zipped file update complete"
Write-Host ""

# Check zip size and individual file sizes after operation (Just to test. Will delete files on your computer!!!!)
Write-Host "test zip file size after replacement: $(Get-ChildItem $testZipPath | select -ExpandProperty Length)"
$FollowUpTestPath = "$(Split-Path $testZipPath -Parent)\FollowUpTest"
Remove-Item $FollowUpTestPath -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
If(-not (Test-Path $FollowUpTestPath)){New-Item -Path $FollowUpTestPath -ItemType Directory | Out-Null}
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($testZipPath, $FollowUpTestPath)
Write-Host "File sizes after operation: "
Get-ChildItem $FollowUpTestPath | foreach { Write-Host "filename: $($_.Name), length: $($_.Length)"}
```

Comment: When I tested writing an `Entry` stream directly without running `Dispose()` on the `$ZipFile`, the entry's length stayed the same, and the contents were not shortened for shorter updated text.  Your method of `Delete()` and `CreateEntry()` probably works though. I suggest you test with multiple files in the zip and try replacing the text with shorter text. Also, you might want to confirm your error messages assumptions - 'locked' is misleading if the error is caused by a nonexistent .Zip file.

Comment: I updated the code to clean up the errror handling a bit. I also added code to generate a test condition of 10 files where we add a bunch of data into a single one and then check the file sizes to confirm it is actually saving the file. Like you said, the `Dispose` on the `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile` instance is super important, which is why it is in the `finally` statement so that it is disposed of regardless of if an error is thrown or not.